# I am trying to import an image on a pdf Canavas drawImage() but its Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to import an image on a pdf using java script but am getting this error
:

```
TypeError: `image` must be of type `PDFImage`, but was actually of type `undefined
```

The image is in jpg format AND Here is the code for my java script file can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong:

```
const generatePDF = async (name,pic) => {
    const { PDFDocument, rgb} = PDFLib;
    const existingPdfBytes = await fetch("./cert.pdf").then((res) =>
      res.arrayBuffer()
    );
  const exfont = await fetch("./Sanchez-Regular.ttf").then(res =>{
    return res.arrayBuffer()
  })
  

   const pdfdoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)
    
   pdfdoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);

  const myFont = await pdfdoc.embedFont(exfont);

  const pages = pdfdoc.getPages();
  const firstPg = pages[0]

  firstPg.drawText(name,{
    x:300,
    y:310,
    size:50,
    font: myFont,
    color: rgb(.2,0.84,0.67)

  })
  firstPg.drawImage(pic,100,100);
  
  
   const uri = await pdfdoc.saveAsBase64({dataUri: true})
   saveAs(uri,"Certificate.pdf");
  
};

const submitbtn = document.getElementById("submit1")
const inputval = document.getElementById("fname")
const inputcal = document.getElementById("logo1")

submitbtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  const cal = inputcal.value;
  const val = inputval.value;
    
  generatePDF(val,cal) ;
})
```

Comment: The relevant code part is not here. Obviously the `pic` variable is not of the correct type. Show the line where you assign the value.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain Here is where i assigned the value :                                                       <img id="logo1" src="bg.jpg" alt="not found">

Comment: @FlorianCastelain also i am using PDF-LIB and i found this on their website but have no idea how to implement it :                                                                                           
     static of = (ref: PDFRef, doc: PDFDocument, embedder: ImageEmbedder) =>
    new PDFImage(ref, doc, embedder);